# Прогресс-бар добавления данных в базу

Tags: php, mysql, loader

Собственно, как сделать прогресс бар при загрузке файлов понятно, но тут дело в том, что у меня есть функция импорта данных из файла. Загружаем файл мы мгновенно, он ничего не весит, потом разбираем его по каждой строке и заносим в базу:

```
INSERT INTO `datas` ...
```

Это, естественно, делается через AJAX, но вот если данных очень много, хотелось бы какой-то прогресс-бар показать: сколько уже загружено, сколько осталось.

Но я не хочу каждую секунду параллельно обращаться к базе и смотреть, сколько там новых строк, это лишняя нагрузка, я считаю. Возможно ли это как-то сделать иначе?

Comment: Надо где-то хранить id процесса и счетчик. Ajax должен периодически обращаться к счетчику по id процесса. А в базе вы его будете хранить или в файле - как напишете

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, а куда быстрее в теории обращаться будет? Я думаю в файле.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Время основанное на статистике**

Если время разбора одной строки и добавления в базу по сути является константой, то вообще никакого AJAX не требуется. Отправили файл, вернули кол-во строк, умножаете кол-во строк на время разбора и показываете пользователю, что идет обработка.

```
Кол-во строк * время разбора одной строки = общее время выполнения.
```

Конечно, могут быть погрешности во времени, но пару секунд ожидания (+-) пользователя не испугают.

**2. Запись результата в кеш**

Когда вы загружаете файл, вы возвращаете пользователю ID этого файла, теперь пользователь обращается к специальному методу для получения количества обработанных строк каждые 3 секунды (например). Обрабатывающий скрипт пишет кол-во строк в быстрое хранилище , например memcached или redis, то есть в хранилище, где данные хранятся в памяти и доступ к ним осуществляется за O(1). По сути, тысячи запросов в секунду на такое хранилище даже не капли не снизит общую производительность.

---

Вообще тут фантанзия неограничена :) Можно сделать отправку данных пользователю вообще на веб-сокетах и тогда уже сервер будет отправлять данные пользователю, а не пользователь будет откуда-то получать.

Comment: Первый вариант явно не подходит, время будет у всех разное, делаю программу, которой будут пользоваться на своем сервере.

Comment: По второму не понял, никогда ранее этим не пользовался. Что за быстрое хранилище, как в него записывать (php) и как из него что-то получать (javascript)?

Comment: @Shevsky redis, memcached - это key-value хранилища, которые хранят данные в оперативной памяти, благодаря чему доступ к ним осуществляется за О(1). Подключение к ним осуществляется через PHP с помощью драйвера. Я думаю, вы сможете больше о них узнать сделав запрос в поисковую систему. На первых порах Вам хватит и memcached.

Comment: а клиент (javascript) может обратиться к оперативной памяти?

Comment: @Shevsky javascript это клиентский язык и никаким способом не имеет прямого доступа к оперативной памяти сервера. Только написать метод контроллера на PHP который будет обращаться к memcached и получать данные по ID, а JS будет к нему обращаться с каким-то ID.

Comment: Ну я так и думал, по сути это тоже хранение в файле.

Comment: Но, черт, у меня проблема такая, что пока тот запрос с загрузкой в базу не выполнился до конца, я не могу создать другой запрос. Точнее ответ не получается, пока предыдущие запросы не дали ответ.

Comment: @Shevsky Сделайте AJAX запрос асинхронным и он не будет блокировать начало новых операций.